# In the context of how Jesus is interpreted as the Israel in the OT, how does that bridge covenants?

Tags: jesus, new-testament, abraham, israel

Many of the OT scriptures that applied to Israel are applied to Christ in the NT, so that Jesus is the very essence of Israel in a spiritual context. Even the servant psalms in Isaiah, such as Isaiah 42:1–3, that orginally applied to Israel are applied to Christ in the NT (Matthew 12:16–19).

When the young nation of Israel comes out of Egypt, God calls it
"my son" (Exodus 4:22). When Jesus comes out of Egypt, God says
"Out of Egypt have I called my son" (Matthew 2:15).

In Psalm 80:8, God calls Israel a "vine" that He brought
"out of Egypt." Jesus later declares, "I am the true
vine" (John 15:1).

God called Israel "my firstborn" in Exodus 4:22. Yet Paul said
it was Jesus Christ who is "the firstborn of every creature"
(Colossians 1:15).

The clearest example is when God calls Israel "the seed of
Abraham" (Isaiah 41:8). However, Paul later writes that
Abraham's seed does not refer to "many," but to "one,
... which is Christ" (Galatians 3:16). Thus we discover that
repeatedly in the New Testament, statements that once applied to the
nation of Israel are now applied to Jesus Christ. The Messiah is now
"the seed." Therefore, Jesus is the very essence of Israel in a spiritual context.

I'm interested in how this applies to Jews and Gentiles in regards to spanning old and new covenants.

Comment: It's not just verses,  Moses survived order of children killed, so did Jesus in Matthew.

Comment: Israel was a holy nation of priests set apart from the nations that functioned as a vehicle underneath the Abrahamic covenant to bring about the healing of the nations through the promised Messiah. The Messiah through perfect fulfillment of the law & sacrificial obedience to death earned himself an exalted position at God's right hand, but as a human, which made him the perfect mediating High Priest & Ruler to lead the humans out from the corrupt domain of the old creation, bound to failure & death, and into the eternal new creation kingdom complete with a new heaven & earth & bodies to boot.

Comment: The gateway from the old creation to the new was created thru Christ's bodily death, which those following him are united to in a new covenant through the sacrament of baptism where his most righteous & perfect & victorious death is counted as their death & they are spiritually severed from the Old covenant, if Jew, & the curse of the Old Creation, if human, & bound in spirit thru the covenant to Christ & the New Creation. Thus spiritually bound, their bodies are destined to be redeemed at the day of resurrection/judgment to fully participate in the New Creation kingdom &  holy service to God.